# Initialize a bean very early in the process with Spring

Tags: spring

Consider this configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {
  @Bean public Params params() { return new Params(...); }
  @Bean public GlobalServiceInitializer globalServiceInitializer(Params params) 
    { GlobalServiceInitializer.initialize(params); }

  @Bean public ClientA clientA(Service service) { ... }
  ...
  @Bean public ClientZ clientZ(Service service) { ... }

  @Bean public DependsOnParamsA dependsOnParamsA(Params params) { ... }
  ...
  @Bean public DependsOnParamsZ dependsOnParamsZ(Params params) { ... }
}
```

10000ft picture:

- `GlobalServiceInitializer` that is a 3rd party thing I have to call before the `Service` is actually used
- I have numerous clients that depend on the `Service`
- `GlobalServiceInitializer` depends on the `Params` that I want to be Spring managed as I have numerous `DependsOnParams`

I can make all clients depend on `GlobalServiceInitializer` to "force" the initialization order, but that adds a bunch of noise. Is there a better way to keep everything Spring-managed, but still have `GlobalServiceInitializer` be called before `Service` is touched in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DependsOn annotation i believe. See below link:

[DependsOn Annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html)

Comment: Thanks Osman, that similar to what I suggested with "I can make all clients depend on GlobalServiceInitializer". I'm trying to avoid having to put dependencies on all clients to avoid noise.